# How to click on the radiobutton using selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, radio-button, webdriverwait

In below code, not able to click or getText of the radiobutton using xpath & id both.

Please help me to perform above operations.

```
<section class="col-md-12 mb5">
    <div class="well well-cust">
        <label class="radio-inline pl0">
            <input type="radio" name="project_task" value="A" onclick="Javascript:projtasks();" id="radio1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Projects Tasks</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="project_task" value="B" onclick="nonprojtasks(); " id="radio2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Non Projects Tasks</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="project_task" value="C" checked="checked" onclick="assignedTasks();" id="radio3">&nbsp;&nbsp;Assigned Tasks</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="project_task" value="D" onclick="issueAssigned(); " id="radio4">&nbsp;&nbsp;Issues Assigned</label>
    </div>      
</section>
```

Tried to click on the element using xpath & id both.

I tried with below code:

```
//Import data for Radiobutton
String Radiobutton_val = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1));
System.out.println("Radio button 1 = "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"radio1\"]")).getText());
System.out.println("Radio button 2 = "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"radio2\"]")).getText());

if(driver.findElement(By.id("radio1")).getText().equals(Radiobutton_val)) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"radio1\"]")).click();
} else if(driver.findElement(By.id("radio2")).getText().equals(Radiobutton_val)){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"radio2\"]")).click();
}
```

I expect that it should getText of the radiobutton & based on the getText value it should click on the specified radio button

Comment: Firstly check Is that radio button visible at time of you want to click?  and show me output of   System.out.println("Radio button 1 = "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//* 
    [@id=\"radio1\"]")).getText());

Answer (score 0):

I guess your **getText** call returns not the expected string?
You should check the text of the parent label. Try following:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='radio1']//..")).getText().equals(Radiobutton_val)) {                
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='radio1']")).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the *radio button* with the *text* read from the *excel sheet* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  String Radiobutton_val = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1));
  // String Radiobutton_val ="Non Projects Tasks";
  // String Radiobutton_val ="Assigned Tasks";
  // String Radiobutton_val ="Issues Assigned";
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(., '" + Radiobutton_val + "')]"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains(normalize-space())`:

  ```
  String Radiobutton_val = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1));
  // String Radiobutton_val ="Non Projects Tasks";
  // String Radiobutton_val ="Assigned Tasks";
  // String Radiobutton_val ="Issues Assigned";
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(normalize-space(), '" + Radiobutton_val + "')]"))).click();
  ```